# Why does getName() returns null?

Tags: java, string, object, encapsulation

EDIT: Thanks for all the answers! I didn't know that the object `p` in List.java is different from the `p` in Main.java. I passed it as a parameter and it works fine now. Thank you!

In Main.java:

```
        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
        String name = scan.next();
        name+=scan.nextLine();

        String words[]=name.split("\\s");  
        String capitalizeWord="";  
        for(String w:words){  
            String first=w.substring(0,1);  
            String afterfirst=w.substring(1);  
            capitalizeWord+=first.toUpperCase()+afterfirst+" ";  
        }

        Person p = new Person(capitalizeWord);
```

In Person.java

```
    private String name;
    private int age;

    Person(String newName){
        name=newName;
    }

    Person(int newAge){
        age=newAge;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
```

In List.java:

```
public void printInvoice(){
        System.out.println("Enter your age:");
        int age = scan.nextInt();

        Person p = new Person(age);
        System.out.println("Thank you for shopping with us, "+p.getName());
}
```

The last output is

```
Thank you for shopping with us, null
```

I don't know why this is happening. Did I do something wrong? I think the code is correct?

Comment: because you don't set a value for name, you only set an age. The default value for any object is null

Comment: @Stultuske I did prompt the user to input name in the Main.java

Comment: You have created a new instance of Person in List.java "Person p = new Person(age);"; You have to use the same instance created in Main instead of creating a new one. You'll need a method setAge so you can establish that member's value in the instance.

Comment: You have constructors 1st with name (which is string) and 2nd with age (which is integer ), so you are passing the integer value the int constructor is executed. there are couple of way around you can do this in age constructor `name=""`

Comment: @ConfusedCoder true, but that is not related to the p instance of Person of which you call getName()

Comment: About your [previous edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61222788/2) (where you explained your design) beware that's a very weird design, if I understood it correctly. Having an object call an object call an object and so on, in your case, seems pretty weird. You should have a place that creates all those objects, manipulates them and aggregates them.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I agree, it's inefficient if I wanna make a big project, but I'm new at Java, so this is all I could do for now lol. I tried making it so that everything is called from the main method, but then I can't loop to the menu. Thanks for the feedback tho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call a constructor you get a distinct instance of the object. The object created in `Main.java` with a name is stored in a local variable `p` that is only existing in the scope of `Main.java`. In `List.java` you create a second object with an age, but no name. It's also stored in a variable called `p` but that one is in the scope of `List.java` only and has nothing to do with the earlier created object.

It sounds like you want to add the name to the earlier object and not create a new one. For that you should pass the first object as a parameter to the code that adds the age, perhaps like this:

```
public void addAge(Person p) {
  System.out.println("Enter your age:");
  int age = scan.nextInt();
  p.setAge(age);  // will have to make this method in the Person class
  System.out.println("Thank you for shopping with us, "+p.getName());
}
```

Calling `Person p  = new Person(age);` gives a brand new Person object that has no name yet.

Answer (score 2):

You have two constructors. One that accepts a string, one that accepts a number.

In your latest example you called the one that accepts a number and, since there's nothing initializing the `name` member, it gets initialized to `null` as default.

The `p` in `Main.java` has nothing to do with the `p` in `List.java` (they're two different variables), so initializing the former will have no effect on the latter.

Comment: the ```name``` is initialized in the Main.java. Doesn't the value stays?

Comment: And before you ask what you should do to fix this, be aware that it's impossible to answer that question without knowing how `Main.java` and `List.java` are related.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in your **List.java** class, you have instantiated a new `Person` object with `age` as a parameter, so for that object, the name would be `null`, since the two reference variables are pointing to the different `Person` object

The first reference `p` to object `Person` has instantiated the person object using the contructor:-

```
Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Second reference `p` to object `Person` has instantiated the person object using the constructor:-

```
Person(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

You should have used setter to set the property `age` to an already created `Person` object

Answer (score 0):

code that create your `person` -> `Person p = new Person(age);`

constructor called -> `Person(int newAge){
        age=newAge;
    }`

This constructor let the name with his default value.. so `null`